# google.maps.places.Autocomplete position offset inside angular material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material2, google-places-autocomplete, material-dialog, angular-cdk-overlay

I'm using a google autocomplete input inside angular material Dialog.

When the user scrolls a bit down, material Dialog uses a trick and (according to source):
`/** Blocks page-level scroll while the attached overlay is open` .

This in turn adds a `top: -1000px` for example to the document element in the html.

Later when the google autocomplete is shown it's `.pac-container` class takes this offset into account ( the one on the `document` element ).

This causes the dropdown to be in a different location than expected ( not next to the input element to which it is bound ).

I've tried running the dialog in pages with scrolling and without, and that makes the difference.

I dug through the angular components GitHub repository to find the overlay scroll issue. I did not find any configuration that can be passed to `Dialog` or to `autocomplete` to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` uses the `html` tag's position to position itself.

At the same time angular material Dialog sets the `html` element `style.top` value when there is scrolling in the page.

My solution was to remove the `top` style and then restore it.

This solution is specific when the following is true:

1. `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` inside an angular material `Dialog`.
2. The page is scrolled down.
3. The `Dialog` is covering the background so that the user won't notice we removed the top.

Maybe this will help someone.